# how to send variable session from one page to another

Tags: php, html

> On my first page where log.php where my session were pased on log.php by header from index.php and this page contains code

```
<a style="color:white; font-size:30px; text-decoration: none"  href="/mn.php">FR</a>
```

> on mn.php i echo session variable which was declaired earliier in index.php but it doesnt echo anything.
>
> > on mn.php

```
echo $_SESSION['login-id'];
```

> > but variables were assessable on log.php when i pass them  from index.php  with header

```
header('location: index.php');
```

> So, How could we pass these session from one page to another without using header ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `session_start();` at the top of each page, before you attempt to access the `$_SESSION` super global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use session_start() before going to access any session variable, and suppose you want to delete any particular session variable on any page, then you can use unset() method.

Please check basics [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).

Comment: sorry i just forgot that dont know why